# rails_admin plural field names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-admin

I'm using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues) in an app and I'm getting an unexpected error.

In a certain model, I have a field called *_status_id.
When trying to edit that model in rails_admin, I get this error:

> undefined method `*_statu_id'

Obviously, rails_admin thinks my resource is plural, when it is not.
Is there a way of letting Rails/rails_admin know how to use this resource properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"status" has an irregular plural; one which Rails doesn't know about automatically. In `config/initializers/infelctions.rb`, ensure the `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections` block is uncommented, and add the following to it:

```
inflect.uncountable 'status'
```

Comment: Yes, it would be better to give it the `inflect.irregular 'status', 'statuses'`, but that doesn't seem to prevent `"status".singularize #=> "statu"`

Comment: Close enough. It was inflect.singular '*_status', '*_status'.